# Is it crucial to have the system consistent in this theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following theorem:

> Suppose the equation $Ax=b$, with $A \in R_{m\times n}$ and $x,v \in R_n$ is consistent for some given $b$ and let $p$ be a solution. Then the solution set of $Ax=b$ is the set of all vectors of the form $w=p+v_h$, where $v_h$ is any solution of the homogeneous equation $Ax=0$.

This is an extract from a linear algebra book. I understand what the theorem is saying and its proof. My question is how necessary is the consistency prerequisite for this proof to be true? If the initial equation would be inconsistent, its solution set $S$ would be empty, so the set of vectors of the form $w = p + v_h$ with $v_h \in S$ would be also empty, which doesn't seem to invalidate the theorem.

Comment: That seems to be a valid extension of the theorem.  Likely it is not stated that way as (1) not everyone is familiar with vacuous truth and (2) it's a pretty trivial extension that doesn't really add anything in the way of knowledge to the reader.

Comment: The conclusion of the theorem refers to $p$. How would you define $p$ if the system were not consistent?